# wherein with whereDate in eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an array of dates without hour & minutes & seconds
and I want to use this array in a `whereIn` condition for a `datetime` column along with a single `userId` check. The problem is how can I do this with `LIKE` operator that my result contains all of rows that match with my dates?

this is my dates:

```
  array:2 [
    0 => "2030-02-06"
    1 => "2019-02-06"
  ]
```

an this is my query that i want to get all of result and then update them:

```
Point::whereIn("end_time",$dates)
->where("user_id","=",$user->user_id)
->update(['is_in_chart'=>1]);
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the dates with end_time column? If you pass that array in whereIn then what issue you are getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this using `DB::raw` and `DATE()`

```
Point::whereIn(DB::raw("DATE(end_time)"),$dates)
->where("user_id","=",$user->user_id)
->update(['is_in_chart'=>1]);
```